# control-w (delete word) deletes whole line in MariaDB client

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal, mariadb

I've been using the original MySQL client for "eons" and I'm rather accustomed to using bash-like shortcuts in it. One of my more frequently used ones is to use `control-w` to delete the word before the cursor (just like you do in bash).

Currently, with my mariadb client -- if I hit `control-w` it deletes the entire line before the cursor. (which in bash at least is usually `control-u`)

So for example, try it in a standard bash prompt.... or even in a classic MySQL command prompt, if I have a line like:

```
SELECT a,b,c FROM table WHERE column='value'
```

And I have my cursor before `WHERE` the line will look like

```
WHERE column='value'
```

When I really expected it to be:

```
SELECT a,b,c FROM WHERE column='value'
```

I'm using Fedora, and the Maria version installed is:

`[doug@talos werk]$ sudo rpm -qa | grep -i maria
mariadb-10.0.21-1.fc21.x86_64
mariadb-config-10.0.21-1.fc21.x86_64
mariadb-common-10.0.21-1.fc21.x86_64`

Other shortcuts work as anticipated, `control-a` and `control-e` to go beginning and end of line respectively, and `control-[left arrow]` moves a word left (or right with right arrow)

I'm running the client with:

```
mysql -A --host=foo.local -u user -p'mypass'
```

I can't find a reference to a maria client config options, like a `.mariarc` or something. I'm happy to take any pointers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've figured out what's need to be done, and I found the answer in the [Mysql Tips article in the mysql manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-tips.html).

Turns out that the behavior depends on what library MySQL was compiled against, `readline` or `libedit`. And you can customize the behavior with a `.editrc` file.

In my case, to have `control+w` work as I anticipated it, you would have a `.editrc` file that looks like:

```
bind "^W" ed-delete-prev-word
```

If you'd like to see what the keybindings are, just put the word `bind` in `.editrc` (or at the end of an existing `.editrc` file)

Comment: It's ridiculous that this isn't the default configuration with MySQL/MariaDB.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, just to clarify location of the mentioned config /home/<user>/.editrc
Also you may place .editrc to the /etc/skel/ directory, so all new users will automatically get these settings

Comment: Be aware that this doesn't seem to work for mysql/libedit shipped with Ubuntu 20.04: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=975911

Comment: I ended up building my own Debian packages for MariaDB that are linked against readline instead. Instructions here: https://wiki.andybev.com/doku.php?id=how_to_rebuild_mariadb_against_readline_in_debian

Comment: I happened to meet "Monty" at a conference.  Someone asked, "Hey!  What editor do you use?"  He replied, blandly, "Emacs", as if it was a weird question,  Every one burst out laughing.